# What is clipbrdDefaultReg

Tags: linux, os-clipboard

Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/171558

What does `let g:clipbrdDefaultReg = '+'` mean?

Comment: it is a variable. What script of plugin that one uses, cannot be seen from the script.

Comment: probably from [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are configured via *global variables*, defined in your `~/.vimrc`. As this file is read *before* any plugins are loaded, this is a convenient way to configure plugins.

Most plugins prefix those variables with their name (`g:PluginName_ConfigVar`); this plugin is old and does not, but @mMontu found it nonetheless: [clipbrd](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1014). Usually the plugin page (or the initial comment block at the top of the script) has an explanation of the config variables and possible values.

If you don't have a `plugin/clipbrd.vim` file in your `~/.vim/` folder, you can safely drop this line.